# How to Vlook up this in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vlookup

I have reference Id and timestamp columns in sheet 1 and sheet 2. Reference Id in the both the sheets are same  but not in the same order and timestamp is different in both sheets. What I want to do is to get the timestamp from sheet 1 and sheet 2 for the same reference ID. I need to do it for more than 36000 reference Id cells. Please help.

Sheet 1
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2
[image]

Expected Output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there only one line for each Reference ID in each sheet? How do you need the output? Only the two timestamps?

Update

In the expected output sheet you'll have two vlookups:

```
Column A | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
------------------------------------------------------
Row 1    | Ref ID 1 |vlookup-1 |vlookup-1 | =(B1-C1) |
------------------------------------------------------
Row 2    | Ref ID 2 |   ''     |   ''     |   ''     |
------------------------------------------------------
Row 3    | Ref ID 3 |   ''     |   ''     |   ''     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Where

vlookup1 =VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$36000,2,FALSE)

vlookup2 =VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$36000,2,FALSE)

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this and let you know the outcome @maverick